# How to open a firefox addon html file in /data folder in a popup without navigation, menu etc. buttons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am making a firefox addon in which i need to open a html page (stored in my /data folder) in a popup without any navigation, menu etc. buttons. It's supposed to look like the popout window in gtalk?

I have tried opening this popup from *main.js* using:

```
require('sdk/windows').browserWindows.open(data:url('file.html'))
```

This only opens the html page in a new window? Now when I pass the `data.url` of this file to the contentscript of my panel in the addon it doesn't do anything at all (its receiving the url from *main.js* and printing in the console, but it doesnt open it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with a window at the moment, unless you go very low level, because this is prevented since it usually isn't safe and it is usually bad UX.

I would suggest using a [Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) instead.